# Adding view model causes view updates to fail

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I'm attempting to separate my model and view by adding a view model as a bridge. When I do this in the following code, clicking on the 'Increase Score' button no longer triggers a view update. It works if I connect the view directly to the model. Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MVVM_Test_Watch_AppApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}

class Model {
    var score = 0
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var model: Model
    
    init() {
        model = Model()
    }
    var score: Int {
        model.score
    }
    func incScore() {
        model.score += 1
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your score is \(viewModel.score)")
            Button("Increase Score") {
                viewModel.incScore()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn’t the ViewModel’s fault. You should review the Apple SwiftUI Tutorials. Model must be a struct or an ObservableObject with its own “Object” property wrapper so you can see changes.

Comment: Making Model a struct worked, but not sure why. Keeping Model as class and making it ObservableObject with Published property didn't work. I'll try digging up the tutorial on this.

Comment: What's an "Object" property wrapper?

Comment: Having an `@Published var model` is pretty pointless; you aren't ever going to change the value of the `model` property.  A computed property won't trigger view updates because it can't be `@Published`.  You could trigger the update by calling `objectWillChange` in your `incScore` function, but generally, view models are. It necessary in SwiftUI. They add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: StateObject, ObservedObject, EnvironmentObject

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` struct hierarchy is a view model already that's separate from the real views that are auto-generated.

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI use `View` structs instead of classes for your view model data. For a timer it is `TimelineView`. Use `@State` for the score or struct that has the score and logic via mutating func.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in models within SwiftUI, `struct` is used, and while this might not be the exact cause of the issue you're encountering.

In your code, a minimal change to detect updates and refresh the view would be to add `objectWillChange.send()` to the function. Here's a sample code for reference:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MVVM_Test_Watch_AppApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}

class Model {
    var score = 0
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var model: Model
    
    init() {
        model = Model()
    }
    var score: Int {
        model.score
    }
    func incScore() {
        model.score += 1

        objectWillChange.send()

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your score is \(viewModel.score)")
            Button("Increase Score") {
                viewModel.incScore()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can consider using `@Published` in the following way:

```
 class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var model: Model
    @Published var score: Int

    init() {
        model = Model()
        score = model.score
    }

    func incScore() {
        model.score += 1
        score = model.score
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use a class Model because in my actual code, the model contains a timer, and that only works with references. Thanks for your solution, it works. I'm debating switching to a new way though, see post below.

Answer (score 0):

According to this migration [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro), there's a new way to handle observation. I updated and tested my code.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MVVM_Test_Watch_AppApp: App {
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

@Observable
class Model {
    var score = 0
}

@Observable
class ViewModel {
    private var model: Model
    
    init() {
        model = Model()
    }
    var score: Int {
        model.score
    }
    func incScore() {
        model.score += 1
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var viewModel

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your score is \(viewModel.score)")
            Button("Increase Score") {
                viewModel.incScore()
            }
        }
    }
}
```